# AVCaptureAudioDataOutput alternative for visionOS

Tags: swift, avfoundation, visionos

I'm trying to get an AVAudioBuffer on visionOS but I do not seem to find a way that works and that is available on visionOS. Seems only Audio Recording is available on visionOS. Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After few days of investigation I found out that it is possible to achieve realtime Audio Recording on visionOS using AVAudioEngine().